# Team System get-latest-version on checkout

Tags: tfs

We used to use SourceSafe, and one thing I liked about it was that when you checked out a file, it automatically got you its latest version.

Now we work with Team System 2005, and it doesn't work that way - you have to "get latest version" before you start working on a file that you've checked out.

Is there a way to configure Team System (2005) to automatically get the latest version when checking out a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Visual Studio Add-in for this that someone wrote:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/srlteam/archive/2007/03/24/TFS-GetLatest-version-on-check_2D00_out-Add_2D00_In.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want that?

It means that when you check out a file, it will be out of sync with the rest of your files.  Your project may not build or function properly until you update all files.

Answer (score 0):

@Vaibhav: Thanks a lot!

@Jay Bazuzi: I understand what you're saying, but for me it's very important that if a developer is working on a file, it be the lastest version of that file. Otherwise the check in introduces a lot of problems. If for some reason, as a result of the getting latest version, the project doesn't compile, then by all means get the latest version of the whole project. For the way our team works - often check-ins - this is good. If you made changes you want to keep - shelve them.